# use a seperate data file to read variables in groovy

Tags: variables, groovy

I am trying to separate variables data from my actual script groovy file.

```
def test = [a,b,c]
def test2 = ['foo': [a,x,y], 'bar': [q,w,e]]


def function(String var){}
def function2 {
test.each
{ 
    item ->
print test


}
}
```

since my values in the variables are changing constantly but not the script. How do I make my groovy read a variable file and load it during the runtime?

I want it to look something like this maybe.

```
variables.properties
def test = [a,b,c]
def test2 = ['foo': [a,x,y], 'bar': [q,w,e]]
```

main.groovy

```
load ( variable.properties)

def function(String var){}
def function2 {
test.each
{ 
    item ->
print test


}
}
```

Comment: How would you like the file look like?

Comment: @daggett  i updated my question to answer that question

Comment: Do  you need the variable definition to be explicitly Groovy, or can you just use any of the normal data formats (e.g., JSON properties)?

Comment: Any form of data. Preferably yaml . @DaveNewton

Comment: Pretty much all serialization methods support collections.

Comment: Could you show me a code example? I am not very familiar. @DaveNewton

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Groovy, it is possible to evaluate data as Groovy code. This is a powerful technique. It is arguably a bit much for your goals, but would work.

Consider this `config.data` file (it is a Groovy file but can be named anything):

```
test = ['a','b','c']
test2 = ['foo': ['a','x','y'], 'bar': ['q','w','e']]
```

and the `App.groovy` file. It sets up a `Binding` of variables in a `GroovyShell`. The `Config` is evaluated inside the shell, and we can reference the variables in the main app.

```
def varMap = [:]
varMap["test"] = [] 
varMap["test2"] = [:] 

def binding = new Binding(varMap)
def shell = new GroovyShell(binding)

def function2 = { test, test2 ->
    test.each { println "test item: ${it}" }
    test2.each { println "test2 item: ${it}" }
}

// ------ main

// load Config and evaluate it
def configText = new File(args[0]).getText()
shell.evaluate(configText)

def test = varMap["test"] 
def test2 = varMap["test2"] 

function2(test, test2)
```

an example usage:

```
$ groovy App.groovy config.data 
test item: a
test item: b
test item: c
test2 item: foo=[a, x, y]
test2 item: bar=[q, w, e]
```

Comment: ` java.io.FileNotFoundException: config.data (No such file or directory)`  
I get this error

Comment: The `config.data` file must be in the same directory as the `App.groovy` file, and passed on the command-line as noted above.

Comment: Great. Please close your question by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer that helped you most.

Comment: If I wanted to nominate the file in the code, I assume I just replace `args[0]` with the name of the file as a string literal?